# How to deploy c# windows form with sqlite database?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, sqlite

I'm using visual studio 2015. I have the sqlite database in the solution explorer. I've also added the sqlite data base under Application Files. But when I deploy, I think a new database is being created every time the app is opened instead of using the existing database. I'm getting an exception that a certain table was not found.  I've used this "Data Source=my_database.sqlite;Version=3;" relative path in the connection string. How do I make the application to use the existing database instead of creating new ones? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like your DB file is not found. Check the path to the DB in the connection string. Try to set it absolute. If it works, your relative path is wrong and doesn't point to your db.

Comment: It works when it is absolute. But how come the relative path works when it is debug mode and doesn't work in release mode?

Comment: Your debug and release are not in the same folder. Release will work with: `my_database.sqlite` but debug with `..\..\my_database.sqlite` depending on where your database is located.